# Can't see the resources on AWS EKS, after I created a Cluster through CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, eks

I created a basic EKS Cluster from CLI, it created all the resources and I could view them through my CLI (pods, nodes, nameservers etc.)

However when getting into AWS platform, I could find the cluster that I've created, but I can't see any resource there.

The EKS command was:

```
eksctl create cluster --name demo --region eu-west-1 --node-type t3.micro
```

It worked on my friend’s account, got the same configuration and same IAM role. I've tried to change region, remove the instances type, add permissions, but still I can only see the cluster but no resources(on AWS)